# Is there a way to configure usage of ONE custom error page for ALL error codes in tomcat's web.xml?

Tags: tomcat, configuration

As said in the in the title, I want to change default error pages in tomcat and did:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>/error_500.html</location>
</error-page>

 <error-page>
   <error-code>404</error-code>
   <location>/error_404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Is it possible to use wildcard error codes like

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>*</error-code>
  <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

?

(The example above doesn't work, but is there another way?)

Thanks

Comment: The way I read the scope "defined by the community" above, I find it erroneous to close this question as off topic. The question is both refering to "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". When in doubt, moderators should opt to leave open rather than close, for stackoverflow to remain relevant to us users (based on the notion that if a user thinks a question relevant enough to ask, it's better to leave it open for others to contribute than not). My two cents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is no way in Tomcat.

The Servlet 3.0 specification supports a global error page as follows:

```html
<error-page>
    <location>/error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

So in theory it should work in at least Tomcat 7.0. But it's not properly implemented in Tomcat 7.0. I have ever reported [issue 52135](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52135) about this, but they denied it. It works on other Servlet 3.0 containers though.

You can however workaround this by implementing a Tomcat-specific [`ErrorReportValve`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.html) class which you then register as [`<Host errorReportValveClass>`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I also read your Bugzilla issue and the comments and double-checked xsd an spec. Unfortunately there is no more comment on your statements about optional usage of error-code or exception-type. Do you think, it's worth it to re-open the issue?

Comment: You can do so. I've experienced the Tomcat devvers to be pretty snarky when it comes to bug reports related to Servlet spec incompliance. I've reported several similar issues related to Servlet spec before; more than often they were immediately closed as invalid (especially by Mark Thomas) and some time later they were eventually reopened and fixed. It's a matter of time :)

Comment: Note that Tomcat [issue 52135](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52135) has now been resolved (and will be included in Tomcat 7.0.29).