# A global error page for tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, global, custom-error-pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to configure usage of ONE custom error page for ALL error codes in tomcat's web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135388/is-there-a-way-to-configure-usage-of-one-custom-error-page-for-all-error-codes-i)

I would like to redirect all HTTP errors (4xx, 5xx) to a global error page. Is there a better solution than adding a lot of error-page elements in my web.xml?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom error reporting Valve and specify it for the Host's errorReportValveClass