# How to handle 404 in application context level

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have 2 applications/projects deployed in tomcat 7 web server. There context paths are different like "project1", "project2". When I hit URLs with these context path, corresponding application loads and works fine.

Valid URLs are:

http://localhost:8080/project1

http://localhost:8080/project2

Now when I hit any wrong URL with correct host name and incorrect context path like **/project3**, it give me error message
**404 not found** and shows a weird screen to the user.

I want to show a proper page with proper message to the end user. How can I do that in web server level?

Comment: @Magnilex Thanks for editing my question. Can you please help me out also ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time for that. By the way, are you really using the JEE stack? For this, an application server like JBoss is typically used. If not, then you have tagged the question with the wrong tags.

Comment: @Magnilex I am working with web server (Apache Tomcat 7.0), not any application server.

Comment: What build of TC-7 are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` file to show some other page than the default for the 404 error - see [here](http://davidghedini.blogspot.de/2010/10/tomcat-custom-404-page.html) for an example.

Extract:

```
<error-page>  
       <error-code>404</error-code>  
       <location>/NotFound.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer. But using this approach I can handle 404 withing a project resources. But I am looking for server level 404. Please read my question again.

Comment: @SunilSharma: I did read your question again, but I'd say my anwer is still valid - your tomcat is trying to serve the wrong URL and has not context for it, so it produces an ugly 404 web page itself. So to handle this individually, you have to adapt tomcat's configuration (the `web.xml` I mentioned) and point it to a nicer error page. This has nothing to do with your deployed projects, it's on server level.

Comment: you are right it works fine !! now its time for beer !!

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should be able to modify the *web.xml* of the default tomcat web application, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135388/is-there-a-way-to-configure-usage-of-one-custom-error-page-for-all-error-codes-i), that doesn't work for Tomcat 7.

Your other option is to extend the standard [`ErrorReportValve`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/ErrorReportValve.html). I have "borrowed" very liberally from the existing `ErrorReportValve` code:

```
    public class Custom404Valve extends ErrorReportValve{

        public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {

           if(request.getStatusCode() != 404){
               super.invoke();
               return;
           }
           // Perform the request
           getNext().invoke(request, response);

           if (response.isCommitted()) {
               if (response.setErrorReported()) {
                   try {
                    response.flushBuffer();
                  } catch (Throwable t) {
                    ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(t);
                  }
               response.getCoyoteResponse().action(ActionCode.CLOSE_NOW, null);
                }
          return;
          }

         response.setSuspended(false);
         //this is where your code really matters
         //everything prior are just precautions I lifted
         //from the stock valve. 
         try {
           response.setContentType("text/html");
           response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
           String theErrorPage = loadErrorPage();
           Writer writer = response.getReporter();
           writer.write(theErrorPage);
           response.finishResponse();
         } catch (Throwable tt) {
           ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(tt);
         }

         if (request.isAsyncStarted()) {
             request.getAsyncContext().complete();
         }
      }

      protected String loadErrorPage() {
          BufferedReader reader = null;
          StringBuilder errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
              try{
                 File file = new File("YourErrorPage.html");
                 reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                    while (reader.ready()) {
                       errorMessage.append(reader.readLine());
                    }
              }catch (IOException e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }finally{
                 try{
                    reader.close();
                 }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              } 
          return errorMessage.toString();     
        }
    }
```

All you now need do is configure the custom valve:

```
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <Valve className="com.foo.bar.Custom404Valve"/>
    </Host>
```

Comment: Have you tried it in Tomcat 7? I haven't, but according to the filed bug in BalusC's answer of your link it was fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Geziefer; I didn't catch the last comment on the linked post (that states that it's been fixed in a new build of TC7), and it wasn't clear to me from the JIRA that it was fixed. We'll let OP confirm. The valve is fairly straightforward. I only added some of the stuff from the stock `ErrorReportValve` because it takes some precautions that I presume are necessary. All OP really need do is what's in the last few lines